# Client-Server Communication Using Web Sockets

Tags: java, c++, jakarta-ee, websocket

I'm developing a Client application which talks to a Server using WebSockets. The Client is in C++ and the Server is in Java.

Can anyone suggest me any library which I can use on both Client side and Server side for communication using web sockets.

Comment: There are 3 similar questions on StackOverflow.. Did you read them?

Comment: No, I couldn't find any similar questions ..

Answer (score 0):

I never had experience with WebSocket, but try library cURL (libcurl). It was easiest for me to write clients for HTTP and FTP, using it. It have to help (but curl is useful just for clients, not for server).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sockets, normal sockets that connect on a port and wait for a connection on the server side and that connect to a given address on the client side, then I would recommend the [boost asio socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) on the c++ side and the [standard java socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) on the java side.

Just remind yourself of making sure that you transmit the datatype you expect.

Another cool implementation for both, java and c++, is [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall). I would recommend to take a look at it because it is easy to use and has implemented some really cool communication patterns.